# Retrieve DocumentName/ID from DocumentDB

Tags: c#, xamarin, azure-cosmosdb

I am using DocumentDB in xamarin mobileapp project where I just need to Retrieve the documentID/Name ONLY and not the actual data what the document contains.

I have tried this but as of now I am getting the entire data along with documentID/Name.

Any help this appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use SQL to project the property you need like `SELECT c.id FROM c WHERE <filter>`.